# Amazon (AWS) API Gateway - Authentication

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ssl, aws-api-gateway

I have a python microservice which I would love to connect to AWS API Gateway. - The problem is that I have researched ways to make both secure, but not really came to a conclusion.

I came across a site saying I should use SSL Certifications to *only* enable requests from API Gateway.

Can someone enlighten me on what's the best practice for authentication between the client and API Gateway and the API itself?

Answer (score 3):

There are a very large number of ways to authenticate between the client and API Gateway. There is no "best" way.

To authenticate between API gateway and the back-end servers, you would use SSL authentication as described here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-client-side-ssl-authentication.html

Comment: I looked into this client certifications but cannot find any documentation supporting how to verify this on Python.

Comment: I searched for flask ssl client certificate auth :o

Comment: @JuLiAnc when I search for that I get multiple results like https://github.com/ContinuumIO/flask-ssl-authentication and https://github.com/stef/flask-tlsauth

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of approaches to implement authentication in API gateway. Different approach serves different purposes and level of security you expects to achieve.

For most of the cases you can write your [custom authorizer lambda](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html) for authentication. With help of JWT you can create a reasonably secure Authentication for your API. If you use IAM authentication API Gateway directly supports it. Only limitation is you need to use AWS SDK to invoke the API for convenience. Since API gateway uses SSL by default, data transfer is already encrypted.

If you have very specific security requirements then you can use SSL certificates. This is generally preferred when communicating between API's in Service Orchestration like scenarios in SOA.

Answer (score 1):

You ask what the "best practice" is, and, since we are in Amazon's AWS ecosystem, that's surely to use [AWS Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/).

If you go this route, you will have vendor lockin for your authentication flow, but it works very well as they are built to play nicely together. Logins occur via calls to AWS Cognito endpoints: successful ones will receive session tokens which can then be used in future for any API Gateway calls.

To enable, just click into any API Gateway Method, click into Method Request, edit Authorization, and you will see your AWS Cognito User Pools you have created.

This takes a bit of configuration, but it works very well.