# How to authenticate requests in AWS API Gateway securely with a web app

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, jwt, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to make an AWS API Gateway endpoint that can authorize my JWT.

This is not possible with custom (Lambda) authorizers because they require a signed Authorization header which requires an IAM User's AWS Access Key and secret. An untrusted source, like a web app, cannot keep secrets, so we can't bundle the Access key into the client-side app. Therefore, this custom authorizers aren't suitable for web apps.

The only way to implement authentication of a JWT in API Gateway is to implement the authentication logic into the Lambda function itself.

Does anyone disagree? Are there security flaws? Is this a misuse of API Gateway?

This question as been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36977940/amazon-aws-api-gateway-authentication) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45333690/securing-aws-api-gateway), but never adequately answered.

Comment: Just create your custom lambda authorizers, validate your jwt token by your way, allow or deny access client method by your rules. Example with nodejs https://github.com/awslabs/aws-apigateway-lambda-authorizer-blueprints/blob/master/blueprints/nodejs/index.js

Comment: @hoangdv - but I still need a signed Auth header, right?

Comment: You can push anything to `Authorization` header to pass this check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use Authorizer in API gateway for achieving this. There are multiple Authorizers possible in API Gateway.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-control-access-to-api.html

Comment: How to overcome my concerns about signing using the IAM access secret?

Comment: For UI development, I use AWS Amplify and by default, it has libraries for authentication using Cognito user Pool, federation, SignV4 Signed URL feature, SRP, lot more.

Comment: My issue was that, although I had correctly set the Lambda Authorizer, I failed to redeploy to any stage. Oops! Thanks for your help!